# Which browsers allow cross domain ajax calls with Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *?

Tags: javascript, ajax, rest, jsonp

Which browsers allow cross domain ajax calls with `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`? I am setting a REST service and trying to decide if I need to support JSONP to allow cross domain javascript access or if it is good enough to set the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

[Here's one reference](http://caniuse.com/#search=cors) suggesting that support in modern browsers is reasonable (but see the note at the end of this answer), assuming client-side code handles the IE issue on purpose. (IE8 and IE9 support CORS, but not via `XMLHttpRequest` —you have to use `XDomainRequest` instead, and it's worth noting that neither [jQuery](http://jquery.com) nor [Prototype](http://prototypejs.org) does that for you in their ajax wrappers — I don't know about [other libraries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_JavaScript_libraries). IE10 *finally* gets it right.) That page says, in essence, that [CORS](http://www.w3.org/TR/access-control/) is supported in the desktop versions of:

- IE8+ (via `XDomainRequest`), IE10+ (properly)
- Firefox 3.6+
- Safari 4.0+
- Chrome 6+
- Opera 12.1+

...as well as

- iOS Safari 3.2+
- Android browser 2.1+

You have to ask yourself what your target market is and whether they're likely to still be using older versions of IE, because [it matters quite a lot](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2010/10/ie6-undead-browser.html) who you're targeting. <s>But overall, you still (for the moment) probably want to look at a JSONP interface — even in the U.S. mostly-home market, IE6+IE7 = about 20% of the users. I don't know many sites that can just ignore a fifth of the market. :-) And if you look at corporate users, or users in Asia or Africa or Central America, that number goes up markedly.</s> The foregoing was true in 2010. Here in 2013, China is really the only holdout using IE6 (>24% there). Worldwide, IE6 and IE7 users have moved on to IE8 and IE9, and even big corporate and government users have finally "got it" about the security risks. IE8 will be with us for a while (as that's has high as IE goes on Windows XP), but you can bet the nearly 20% using IE9 will be on IE10 soon.

Comment: Pity I cannot vote twice (once for the support table, once for the warning against minimizing the number of IE 6(/7) users).

Comment: The good news is that the figures related to the last paragraph are now plummeting quite quickly. IE6 in the U.S. market is now under 1%; I don't have a figure for IE7 because NetApplications is now charging (understandably!) for their geographic filter. But IE7 worldwide has only about two-thirds of IE6's market share, so for the U.S. home market, we're probably there. Oddly, Opera 11 **still** doesn't support CORS, but 12 supposedly will.

Answer (score 0):

I had some problems when using Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *. I believe it had something to do with cookies and preflight request(POST). So it is better to specify from which domain you are going to make these calls.

Comment: This is correct. Many browsers will simply ignore `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` if it is set to the `*` wildcard.