# Error using $.ajax type GET on IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, facebook, token

I can't run this script on IE, and I know why, because on debugger 'F12' I can see nothing, on other browsers it works (FF, CH and Safari). This script gets a token from facebook and after will save to the database (the function that saves to the database is `end()`).

```
function NewPage2() {

     var url2 = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id="
            + '<%=ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["clientId"].ToString() %>' + "&redirect_uri="
            + '<%=ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["redirectUrl"].ToString() %>' + "&state="
            + document.getElementById('text').value + "&client_secret="
            + '<%=ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["client_secret"].ToString() %>'
            + "&code=" + getUrlVars2()["code"];
     $.ajax({
         url: url2,
         type: 'GET',
         success: function (res) {
             alert("success" + res);
         },
         error: function (res) {
             alert("Error" + res);
         }
     });
            }


function getUrlVars2() {
        var vars = [], hash;
        var url = location.href.replace("#_=_", "");
        var hashes = url.slice(url.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
        for (var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++) {
            hash = hashes[i].split('=');
            vars.push(hash[0]);
            vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
        }
        return vars;
    }
```

Comment: post the code of all the other methods you call such as getUrlVars2 and end(), people need to see it all to help

Comment: ok, on end() function it's not important because on IE a have error on NewPage2(), a need values on function (res).

Comment: I thought you said the developer tools didn't show an error?

Comment: no, i don't have no error on developer tools

Comment: So how do you know you have an error on NewPage2()?

Comment: because, i'm doing debug(F10), i'm enter on error:

Comment: What is the error you get from that? What is the value of res?

Comment: Its going to be impossible to solve this with out more code or an explanation of what type of error your getting?

Comment: i have a lot of objects: abort, always ... then 
so sorry but i don't know the developer tool on ie

Comment: but on argumets i have this:
[1] "error"
[2] "No Transport"

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the version of IE you are using (see for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4403865/which-browsers-allow-cross-domain-ajax-calls-with-access-control-allow-origin)), the problem might be related to cross-domain AJAX requests being denied. In any case, try adding `&callback=?` to the request URL in order to use [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) instead. See the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) for more information about using JSONP with jQuery.