# jquery post error when using .NET HttpListener

Tags: jquery, .net

I have javascript on a html page without a webserver (file://). On the page I have javascript that does this

```
$.post("http://localhost:1234/", json_data ).fail(function(){alert('Fail');});
```

This worked fine without the `.fail`. I need to send the data to my .NET app. But I'd like to get an alert when it fails for some reason (like forgetting to launch the app). But when I add the `.fail` I get it 100% of the time even if my .NET code sees the commend and runs as expected. The below is the .NET code. Why do I get an error/fail? I tried looking at the error message it was simply "error". I tried looking at the response in firebug and I couldnt see the response although I could see the response length and the server (some MS/.NET header like MS HTTP API)

```
HttpListener listener = new HttpListener();
listener.Prefixes.Add("http://localhost:9001/");
listener.Start();
//...
HttpListenerContext context = listener.GetContext();

HttpListenerRequest request = context.Request;
var data = new StreamReader(request.InputStream).ReadToEnd();
//...
HttpListenerResponse response = context.Response;

string responseString = @"{""command"":""Success""}";
byte[] buffer = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(responseString);

response.ContentLength64 = buffer.Length;
System.IO.Stream output = response.OutputStream;
output.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without the fail function the error is just ignored.

The problem is that you cannot post to a different domain than the domain used to load the HTML page. This conflicts with the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy).

A file loaded from disk with `file://` has a different origin than `http://localhost:1234`. You should load your HTML with `localhost` as your domain.

Comment: Yep, that worked. I added this line and it fixed everything `context.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");`

Comment: Cool, be aware that this header is not supported be all browsers. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4403865/which-browsers-allow-cross-domain-ajax-calls-with-access-control-allow-origin